# Symfony 2.7 return object Twig

Tags: validation, symfony

I'm trying to validate by symfony,
the validate with Entity of symfony.
on RegisterAction , route /regiter
....

```
  $errors = $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->get('errors'); 
    return array(
        'title' => $title , 
        'user' => $user , 
        'login' => $login , 
        'home_categories' => $home_categories ,
        'categories' => $categories , 
        'posts' => $posts , 
        'cities' => $cities ,
        'areas' => $area , 
        'year' => $year,
        'month' => $month,
        'day' => $day,
        'errors' => $errors
      );
```

on register post check

```
$user = New User;
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($user);
if (count($errors) > 0)
{
    $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('errors', $errors);
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('register'));
}
```

---

on the twig:

```
{% for error in errors %} <li>{{ error.message }}</li> {% endfor %}
```

but i get this message:

> Method "message" for object
>   "Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationList" does not exist
>   in src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Default/Register.html.twig at line
>   187`

The version is Symfony 2.7.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a nested array, try rewriting:

```
$errors = $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->get('errors'); 
return array('errors' => $errors);
```

to:

```
return $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->get('errors', [] );
```

The second argument is the default value if there is no value for the key 'errors' in the flashBag.

The error message shows you the `error` variable in your loop is actually a `ConstraintViolationList`. As a `ConstraintViolationList` implements `iteratorAggregate` you can/should iterate over that object itself. It's currently nested inside an array with the `ConstraintViolationList` the (only?) object.

You can use `dump()` inside twig to show you the contents of a variable.

**Example**

Here's a basic example of how you can use the `ConstraintViolationList`

```
/* @var $errors ConstraintViolationList */
$errors = $validator->validate( $something );

/* @var $error ConstraintViolation */
foreach( $errors as $error )
{
    echo $error->getMessage();
}
```

Just make sure that the `errors` variable in your twig is in fact the `ConstraintViolationList`, it should work.

For more info:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#using-the-validator-service

Comment: the : return array('errors' => $errors); it's only shourtcut, what actally i have,

Comment: Could you remove your answer and post it as an edit instead? It's a bit unclear now.

Comment: why not ? when i do var_dump($errors) , it's show me the errors, with "message" array

Answer (score 0):

I think that you wrap errors in another array somewhere before.
Try with this:

```
{% for error in errors.0 %}
   <li>{{ error.message }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```